# Using PHP sleep to give priority to some requests - a good or bad idea?

Tags: php

I'm running an ecommerce site where we at times experience high peak loads.

After a certain number of customers is exceeded, some very simple overload control actions will be taken.

One of the planned actions it to give priority to those customers having items in their shopping carts, for very obvious reasons.

This is done by adding a short sleep (or usleep) to all other requests but those from customers with items in cart.

Is this a good idea?

a) Yes, it Will it work like a dream!

b) It will not have a significant impact on anything...

c) No, it will just reserve resources unnecessarily and slow everything down!

d) Well, it depends... (on what?)

Comment: sleep() also one process...

Comment: Code optimisation depends on many things, but I don't think making some people wait more than others can be called optimisation. Better identify the bottleneck(s) in your app and see if you can change that by optimizing code, caching, SQL queries, SQL indexes, adding more ressources to the server, etc...

Comment: First what is a load peak? A load on the bandwidth, on the cpu of the server, on the file io, on the database?

What you are describing is throttling. However it does reduce the responsiveness of a low priority user as the script stalls for him/her.

Comment: No one of the options you gave us sounds good.

To my eyes a good solution could be to implement another server (like a mirror) and serve the request in a kind of round-robin-fashion or with load balancing. There are nice software that you can put in front of your webservers and that can do it for you (if "peak" is referred to "many connection" at the same time)

Comment: It's a hack fix, it doesn't solve the problem, it simply buries it, whilst creating a new one. Now Ms Doris with a $0.10 screw in her shopping car has priority over Mr Jenkins who's trying to access your site to buy $500 worth of electronic supplies, but is getting pissed off with the sluggish response and is considering going elsewhere. Do some better research, find the true bottleneck and fix it, either via optimisation or upgrading your infrastructure to cope with demand.

Comment: add caching. add resources. optimize code. anything but this :)

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware that in perfect world there would be a loadbalancer, a number of servers, autoscaling and stuff. But we don't have that just yet.

And this is  not about code optimization, i.e. making it run faster, increasing troughput, overall responsiveness or anything like that. It is about giving some priority over some others. In a one server configuration.

Comment: `And this is not about code optimization` it will most likely be something that can be improved/solved with it. Unless your code/service is already _absolutely perfect_. What is causing the bottleneck that you're experiencing? Memory? Bandwidth? CPU?

Comment: Testing still needed, but my current understanding is that CPU is the bottleneck.

Comment: Caching / Database optimisation would be the first thing to look into then. Do you have decent Indexes setup? Do you perform any unnecessary queries? Check your slow query log, use `EXPLAIN` on your most frequently used queries and identify how they could be improved.

Comment: @MLeFevre and how does this give priority to those with items in the cart?

Comment: @TeroLahtinen Those with items in the cart will experience considerably less downtime & problems in the coming months, slight decreases in prices on the site due to less of the budget being spent on patching holes with duct tape, and thus savings potentially being passed onto them, better responsiveness across the entire site and increased chances of seeing new features sooner.

Comment: But in the format you wanted, then `c) No, it will just reserve resources unnecessarily and slow everything down!`

Comment: @MLeFevre, the code is perfect, there is enough hardware, and we have just done everything perfectly. But still our assumptions fail, the demand exceeds our capacity manyfold. We have failed. We can only limit the disaster. The only, **the one and only** thing we care about to is that the most critical requests succeed. We do **not care at all** if all the others fail. How to give priority to the important requests?

Comment: 20 connections with low priority make a request and get told to sleep for 2seconds, 2seconds later a high priority request gets received, that high priority request will still be affected by the low priority requests as they have now just re-activated. That solution **does not work reliably**. It's as simple as that. You need to think of a better bad solution - redirect any user not logged in/no items in basket to a "we are experiencing high load page" (and do no processing for them) at peak points during the day? Some database queries also support things like a `HIGH/LOW_PRIORITY` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`c - it will just reserve resources unnecessarily and slow everything down.`

Sleep won't free up resources, because the script is still running. Each time a user makes a request to your site, a new PHP thread is spawned and takes up memory. The more running threads, the more memory being used. By sleeping, you are actually taking up MORE memory by delaying each thread and making it run longer.

What you can do is open your developer console in firefox or chrome, go to the network tab, and press refresh. Look at all the network resources that are loading and think about how you can decrease that loadtime and the number of requests to the server. Maybe you have 10 or 50 queries per page, when you really only need 4-5. Optimize your site code and network utilization to speed it up.

If you post the link, we can take a look at it too.

Comment: Yes, I understand that more memory is consumed, but what if the bottleneck is CPU?

(going from 4-5 queries from 50 is not giving anyone priority over someone else, which is the idea here)

Comment: Each network request takes up CPU, and each database query takes up CPU. You're trying to focus on prioritizing one user over the other, when you should focus on making your application take less time to load for everyone.

Comment: the importance of every request is just not the same. It is very imporant to register customer coming back after payment, not at all important to let a new customer in, when there are already more than we can handle.